# how to generate jar file containing java package from xsd using xmlbean

Tags: javac, xmlbeans

I am generating a jar file from *xsd* using *xmlbean* with the `scomp` command, however the jar file is showing the package as *noNameSpace* while I need it to be different.

For this I already put `xsdconfig` file in *schemas* folder of *xmlbean*.

Below is my `xsdconfig` file:

```
<xb:config xmlns:xb="http://xml.apache.org/xmlbeans/2004/02/xbean/config">
  <xb:namespace uri="##any">
    <xb:package>com.hello</xb:package>
  </xb:namespace>
  </xb:config>
its generating jar file but package name is not intended.
```